# Localization using resources files doesn't work

Tags: kendo-ui, localization

I'm trying to implement the localization of the Kendo widgets, using the resources files, following the steps as shown [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#localized-user-interface).

I'm unsuccessful every time, the Kendo messages never change, even though I change the UI culture of the application.

I have followed the specified link perfectly but still without any output. Can anybody describe how to implement it in a little bit detail?

I'm storing the locale in the session in the controller of the application. Then I get the value in the `Application_AcquireRequestState` function in the global.asax file. There, I set my `CurrentUICulture` as `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture=new new CultureInfo(langName)`.

Comment: How are you setting your `CurrentUICulture`?

Comment: @Vash: Firstly i am storing the locale in session in controller of the mvc 4 and i get the value in the Application_AcquireRequestState function in the global.asax file ,there i set my CurrentUICulture as 'Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture=new new CultureInfo(langName)'